# Jinjia 2 flask how to count a list length in OrderedDict

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

for example, my results print on the terminal as

```
OrderedDict([ (<apple>, [<banana 1>, <banana 2>]) ])
```

I want to know how many items in banana
I tried for loop and length, but I got value = 0
Is there any way to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Jinja2 filter to count the items or better still write a custom filter if what you need to do is more than just counting. Check the doc [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#length).